# style sheets doesn't display on web host

Tags: html, css, layout, coding-style

I trying to create my first website and encounter problem with displaying style sheets. In offline mode it works fine (it means when it previewed in chrome from my hard drive). However when it's load from webhost (particularly 000webhost.com) it's seems display some properties of my css, however the bits with divs look like squeezed. Also I noticed that during slow loading it's appeared as should, then after fool load it's back to it's 'squeezed version'. Have anyone an idea it's fault of my code (which is completely in mess) or the host provider?
There is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<!-- <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://cooldoodling.com/cooldoodling.html">-->
<title>CoolDoodling.com</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>
<script src="base64.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="canvas2image.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
var bMouseIsDown = false;
var oCanvas = document.getElementById("thecanvas");
var oCtx = oCanvas.getContext("2d");
oCanvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
    bMouseIsDown = true;
    iLastX = e.clientX - oCanvas.offsetLeft + (window.pageXOffset||document.body.scrollLeft||document.documentElement.scrollLeft);
    iLastY = e.clientY - oCanvas.offsetTop + (window.pageYOffset||document.body.scrollTop||document.documentElement.scrollTop);
}
oCanvas.onmouseup = function() {
    bMouseIsDown = false;
    iLastX = -1;
    iLastY = -1;
}
oCanvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
    if (bMouseIsDown) {
        var iX = e.clientX - oCanvas.offsetLeft + (window.pageXOffset||document.body.scrollLeft||document.documentElement.scrollLeft);
        var iY = e.clientY - oCanvas.offsetTop + (window.pageYOffset||document.body.scrollTop||document.documentElement.scrollTop);
        oCtx.moveTo(iLastX, iLastY);
        oCtx.lineTo(iX, iY);
        oCtx.stroke();
        iLastX = iX;
        iLastY = iY;
    }
}

function clearCanvas(){
      document.getElementById('resetbtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }, false);
}
function showDownloadText() {
    document.getElementById("buttoncontainer").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("textdownload").style.display = "block";
}

function hideDownloadText() {
    document.getElementById("buttoncontainer").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("textdownload").style.display = "none";
}

function convertCanvas(strType) {
    if (strType == "PNG")
        var oImg = Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(oCanvas, true);
    if (strType == "BMP")
        var oImg = Canvas2Image.saveAsBMP(oCanvas, true);
    if (strType == "JPEG")
        var oImg = Canvas2Image.saveAsJPEG(oCanvas, true);

    if (!oImg) {
        alert("Sorry, this browser is not capable of saving " + strType + " files!");
        return false;
    }

    oImg.id = "canvasimage";

    oImg.style.border = oCanvas.style.border;
    oCanvas.parentNode.replaceChild(oImg, oCanvas);

    showDownloadText();
}

function saveCanvas(pCanvas, strType) {
    var bRes = false;
    if (strType == "PNG")
        bRes = Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(oCanvas);
    if (strType == "BMP")
        bRes = Canvas2Image.saveAsBMP(oCanvas);
    if (strType == "JPEG")
        bRes = Canvas2Image.saveAsJPEG(oCanvas);

    if (!bRes) {
        alert("Sorry, this browser is not capable of saving " + strType + " files!");
        return false;
    }
}

document.getElementById("savepngbtn").onclick = function() {
    saveCanvas(oCanvas, "PNG");
}
document.getElementById("savebmpbtn").onclick = function() {
    saveCanvas(oCanvas, "BMP");
}
document.getElementById("savejpegbtn").onclick = function() {
    saveCanvas(oCanvas, "JPEG");
}

document.getElementById("convertpngbtn").onclick = function() {
    convertCanvas("PNG");
}
document.getElementById("convertbmpbtn").onclick = function() {
    convertCanvas("BMP");
}
document.getElementById("convertjpegbtn").onclick = function() {
    convertCanvas("JPEG");
}

document.getElementById("resetbtn").onclick = function() {
    var oImg = document.getElementById("canvasimage");
    oImg.parentNode.replaceChild(oCanvas, oImg);
    hideDownloadText();

}

}

</script>
</head>
<body class="body">
    <div id="big_wrapper" >
        <header id="top_header">
            <h1>Welcome do Doodling.com!</h1>
        </header>
        <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://cooldoodling.com"
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
        style="border:none; width:450px; height:80px"></iframe>

        <nav id="top_menu" role="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>About project</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div id="container">
        <section id="main_section" role="main">
            <article>
                <header>
                    <hgroup>
                        <div id="pcontainer" style="display:block;">
                            <input type="button" id="snake" value="colour snake">
                            <br/>
                            <input type="button" id="eyes" value="eyes">
                            <input type="button" id="resizebtn" value="Resize">
                            <div id="alertBox">
                                <span id="close" onclick="hide()">X</span>
                                <br/>
                                <div style="clear:both"></div>
                                <p id="alertBoxText">some text.</p>
                                </div>
                            <script>
                                customAlert('some text');
                            </script>
                        </div>
                        <!--<canvas width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid black;" id="thecanvas"></canvas>-->
                        <canvas width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid black;" id="thecanvas"></canvas>
                        <br/><br/>
                        <div id="textdownload" style="display:none;font-style:italic;">Now you can right click and download the image<br/>
                            <input type="button" id="resetbtn" value="Reset">
                            <script>
                                var canvas = document.getElementById('thecanvas');
                                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                                document.getElementById('resetbtn').addEventListener('click', function(){context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                                }, false);
                            </script>

                        </div>

                        <div id="buttoncontainer" style="display:block;">
                            <input type="button" id="savepngbtn" value="Save PNG">
                            <input type="button" id="convertpngbtn" value="Convert to PNG">
                            <br/>
                            <input type="button" id="savebmpbtn" value="Save BMP">
                            <input type="button" id="convertbmpbtn" value="Convert to BMP">
                            <br/>
                            <input type="button" id="savejpegbtn" value="Save JPEG">
                            <input type="button" id="convertjpegbtn" value="Convert to JPEG">

                        </div>
                    </hgroup>
                </header>
                    <p>tutaj wszystko wskakuje</p>
                <footer>
                    <p>-express yourself ;)-</p>
                </footer>
            </article>

        </section>
        <aside id="side_news" role="complementary">
            <a href="photobooth/photobooth.html"<h4>Photo Booth</h4></a>
            see your saved work list
        </aside>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
     <!-- run all the javascript stuff -->
     <script src="processing-1.3.6.min.js"></script> <!-- Include the processing.js commands -->
     <script src="ColourCenitpede.js"></script> <!-- The actual source code for your program -->
     <script type="application/javascript">
        var canvas = document.getElementById("thecanvas"); //get the canvas that processingjs will use
        var processingInstance = new Processing(canvas, sketchProc); //pass the function sketchProc (defined in myCode.js) to Processing's constructor.*/

     </script>
</html>
```

css:

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
 h1{
    font:bold 20px Tahoma;
 }
  h2{
    font:bold 14px Tahoma;
 }
 header, section, footer, aside, nav, article, hgroup{
    display: block; /* block position on after another*/
 }
 body{
    width:100%; /* crucial */
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-pack: center; /*center align boxes*/
    background: black;
 }
 #big_wrapper{
    max-width: 1000px;
    /*minimum-height: 1000px;*/
    margin: 20px 0px;
    -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1; /*allows shrink and gorw horizontally*/
    /*background: #EB8C07;*/
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(180deg, brown,red);
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(110,110,200, 0.7) 10px 10px 10px inset;

 }
 #top_header{ /*logo itp*/
    background:yellow;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    -webkit-border-radius:25px; /*round corners*/
    /* rgb range 0-256 + transperancy alpha, right-left, down, blur, inside- inset*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(110,110,100, 0.7) 10px 10px 10px inset;
    padding: 20px;
 }
  #top_menu{
    border: red;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
 }
   #top_menu li{
    display:inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px;
    font: bold 14px Tahoma;
    -webkit-transition: webkit-transform 2s, opacity 2s, background 2s;
    -webkit-border-radius:25px;
 }
 #top_menu li:hover{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    opacity: 1;
    background: #1ec7e6;

 }
  #new_div{
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    text-shadow: rgb(110,110,110) 3px 3px 5px;
 }
 article:first-child{
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, circle, red 0%, orange 50%);

 }
 #main_section{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    padding: 20px;
    margin:20px; 
 }
 #side_news{
    border: 1px solid red;

    -webkit-box-flex: 0; /*fixed*/
    width: 220px;
    margin:20px 0px; /* 20px from top i 0 from bottom*/
    padding: 30px;
    /*can be start gradient from top*/
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, orange,violet);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s;
 }
 #side_news:hover}{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
 }
 #the_footer{
    /*clear: both;*/
    text-align:center;
    padding:20px;
    border-top:2px solid green;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(12deg) translate(-100px, -50px) scale(.8);

 }
 article{
    background:#FFFBCC;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 20 px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
 }
 article footer{
    text-align: right;
 }
 #map_canvas {
        width: 500px;
        height: 400px;
        background-color: #CCC;
      }
```

Comment: open in Chrome or Safari and press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `I`, this will bring up the developer tools, select `Console` and read the red lines to know what's going on...

Comment: in HTML5 you don't need self closing tags, and your JavaScript at the bottom of the page should be placed before the closing `</body>` tag, not after